# Properly rename job_name in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In prometheus.yml configuration file, I renamed job_name from "prometheus" to "linux". Now I have 2 separate values for job variable in the grafana dashboard, both "prometheus" and "linux". Some panels have been broken. How to properly rename the job_name?

Comment: Your old data contains label `job` with value `prometheus`. Renaming your job wouldn't be change it's value retrospectively. What does "properly rename" mean?

Comment: "Properly rename" means that in Grafana dashboard I shall see only new value for job variable. Maybe there is a way to change data in Prometheus database? Or regex in dashboard settings?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to retroactively replace labels of your metrics. So you'll have to use `label_replace` function in your queries. Something like `label_replace(my_metric, "job", "linux", "job", "prometheus")`. Or simply wait, while metrics with "prometheus" job become obsolete, and do nothing.